# ZSH prompts [nyae] for changing git branch names

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Every time I try to change the branch, I keep getting this prompt:

```
> git checkout rc/v1.1.1
zsh: correct 'rc/v1.1.1' to 'src/v1.1.1' [nyae]? n
```

It's kind of irritating to keep providing an input. Before the last zsh update, I could simply just type the branch name and checkout.

If I have to avoid the prompt, I have to add the branch name in quotes.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Try `setopt nocorrectall`

Comment: Glad to hear; I've now expanded the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setopt nocorrectall` to disable the `correctall` setting, apparently set by default. In my experience that option is too aggressive to be worth it, because it assumes that everything that looks like a file name is a file name, which leads to problems.

If you like the option normally, but want to avoid it specifically for `git`, an alternative is to keep the option, but use `alias git=nocorrect git`.